# C# timer tick with ofd files

Tags: c#, timer

I have a button that plays a sound that I load once when i click it. I want to set a timer so that the sound plays every 3 seconds, but i don't want to load the file every time. It should just play the same sound. How do i make the timer work, without having to load the sound file over and over?

EDIT: I know that the s.Play() the timer1_Tick is not going to work...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
            timer1.Start();
            s.Play();
        }

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        s.Play();
}
```

Comment: How do i make the timer work, without having to load the sound file over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the sound player out as a class variable:

```
private SoundPlayer s;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        s = new SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
        timer1.Start();
        s.Play();
    }

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    s.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `SoundPlayer` a `private` variable:

```
private SoundPlayer sp;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sp = new SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
            timer1.Start();
            sp.Play();
        }

}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        sp.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to  Make it Global and reach it from anywhere

```
SoundPlayer Global;
int counter;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
        timer1.interval=1000;
        timer1.Start();          
    }
}

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ++counter;
    if(counter%3==0) 
    Global.Play();
    //or another aspect   if (counter==3){Global.Play();counter=0}
}
```